# How to change static private ip address on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Is it possible to change static private ip address on AWS EC2 instance ? In example below I want to change 10.0.0.126 to 10.0.0.5. Unfortunately I only have an option to "add" 10.0.0.5.
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the image shown, 10.0.0.126 is your primary private IP (the IP automatically assigned when you launched the instance). 10.0.0.5 is a secondary private IP that you added after the fact.

You're asking if you can change the primary private IP from the one auto-assigned at launch to a different IP of your choosing.

No, you can't do this directly. You can add secondary IP addresses of your choosing, but you can't change the primary address.

The best option is probably to create an AMI from the image, then terminate the instance, launch a new instance from the captured AMI, and request a specific IP at launch time.